# What GPU should I buy for my current setup?

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards

When running Euro Truck Simulator 2 on medium graphics settings my CPU was at about 20%, my RAM was at about 60% and my GPU was at 100%.

I would like to achieve 30 FPS on high on games like Kerbal Space Program, Euro Truck Simulator 2, Spintires and Cities: Skylines.

Currently I achieve between 15 and 20 FPS in Euro Truck Simulator 2 on medium graphics with shadows turned off.

Spintires is about the same as ETS2 on similar settings.

I also got between 9 and 11 FPS on the Racecraft Techdemo on 40% graphics.

All of my drivers are up up date, however my PC is full of dust and I have just ordered some compressed air to clean it.

My specs are:

- **Operating System**
  Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- **CPU**
  Intel Core i5 2320 @ 3.00GHz
  Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
- **RAM**
  4.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)
- **Motherboard**
  Dell Inc. 0GDG8Y (CPU 1)
- **Graphics**
  Acer S191HQL (1366x768@60Hz)
  1024MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 6450 (Unknown)
- **Storage**
  465GB Western Digital WDC WD5000AAKX-753CA1 ATA Device (SATA)
  465GB Samsung M3 Portable USB Device (USB (SATA))
- **Optical Drives**
  HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GH70N ATA Device
- **Audio**
  AMD High Definition Audio Device

**I benchmarked my PC with NovaBench and these were the results:**

4079 MB System RAM (Score: 149)

- RAM Speed: 11018 MB/s

CPU Tests (Score: 436)

- Floating Point Operations/Second: 102394996
- Integer Operations/Second: 373006004
- MD5 Hashes Generated/Second: 1045838

Graphics Tests (Score: 63)

- 3D Frames Per Second: 204

Hardware Tests (Score: 30)

- Primary Partition Capacity: 450 GB
- Drive Write Speed: 68 MB/s

What GPU should I buy that's compatible with these specifications, that will allow me to run said games?

I am on a quite a tight budget and can only spend around £100 ($150 USD)

Comment: Honestly, with tax and everything, 100 GBP is more like 100 USD, in terms of buying power, even though the exchange rates say otherwise.

Comment: I know the original question referred to purchasing a GFX card and the 750ti suggested by @Peter Zhu will fit the bill, however I do think there is one necessary upgrade. For a very small price you can bump up your RAM from 4GB to 8GB, a couple of [these](http://www.ebuyer.com/237100-corsair-4gb-ddr3-1333mhz-memory-cmx4gx3m1a1333c9) will work a treat for a relatively low price as well.

Answer (score 6):

A GTX 750 or a GTX 750 Ti would suit your needs. Buying a GPU better then the GTX 750 Ti would make your CPU a bottleneck and anything lower than a GTX 750 wouldn't satisfy your needs. Try to get a GTX 750 Ti if it's within your budget (it should be), if not, get a GTX 750. The GTX 750 ti would be good enough to run modern games at low settings and less demanding games at medium or high settings.

Comment: I have found the 750 ti for £95, This seems like it would be perfect for my setup. Thanks. :)

Comment: This is good stuff, but please remember that you should also provide a synopsis of each bit of hardware you recommend, and how it meets the asker's needs. It may help to split this into one answer per recommendation. Please [edit] this answer to include those details. Thanks.